# Is there any way to crawling marketplace.visualstudio.com

Tags: visual-studio-code, web-scraping, web-crawler, marketplace

As this title says, I want to get VS code Plugins' information
Firstly, I need get the urls of Plugins
Secondly, crawling every single Plugin's url to get more information, like it's Categories, and tags and Project Details and so on.

I tried, but failed in the first step.
Or is there open API for us to get those information?

Comment: Check web scraping questions on here to start.

Comment: Please add some code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example